# Canvas rendering bug only on Safari and only on iOS5 / Lion

Tags: canvas, safari, svg, ios5, osx-lion

I've never seen a browser bug quite like this one.  It only happens on a specific Safari browser/platform combination.  I get expected results with Safari 5.1.1 on iOS4 or Mac OSX Snow Leopard, but the bug occurs once I try Safari 5.1 or 5.1.1 only on Lion or iOS5.

This situation occurs when I embed a canvas element into an inline svg doc via the foreignObject element.  The canvas usually respects all the svg transforms applied to the foreignObject and this works fine on Chrome/Firefox and Safari (iOS4, Snow Leopard).  But when I use Safari on Lion, iOS5 the canvas renders without any transforms applied.  The canvas render is also on top of all the SVG so no z-order is respected either.

What could have changed in Safari in the same version (5.1 / 5.1.1) between platforms (Snow Leopard / Lion)?

Any help is appreciated to find a work around.

EDIT: Looks like the rendering engine changed in Lion and iOS5 from Webkit1 to Webkit2 and introduced a ton of bugs.  This one looks like the relevant one:  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68635  Still looking for a workaround...

Comment: Interesting information, but this sounds like a bug report, not a question. You haven't even provided a pared-down test case to let someone reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how are you linking your svg in the html. 
If it is external svg file than you should embed it like this and serve it as "image/svg+xml"

```
<embed id="some_id" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT" src="youranimation.svg" name="animated_map" type="image/svg+xml">
```

If you are inserting it inline, i know some transforms and animations isn't working and don't know any workaround for this at the moment. I would recommend linking it externally how I described.